# How do I add debug/release specific generated source to Android Gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following sourceSet entry.  Each directory contains the autogenerated java source files, which should be compiled for each respective debug/release build.

```
sourceSets {
    debug {
        java.srcDirs = [generatedDebugCodeDir]
    }

    release {
        java.srcDirs = [generatedReleaseCodeDir]
    }
}
```

However, I do not see the directories added to the classpath (by using the --debug Gradle flag).  How should I address this?  I tried java.srcDir (no **S**), which is not even recognized.

One workaround I'm considering is just generating the files in the appropriate generated buildConfig dirs.  Hopefully there's no crazy side effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it will be better for me to use the flavor specific java.srcDirs.  This setup worked for me.

```
    flavor1Debug{
        java.srcDirs = ["${generatedJavaDirRoot}/flavor1/debug/"]
    }
    flavor1Release{
        java.srcDirs = ["${generatedJavaDirRoot}/flavor1/release/"]
    }
    flavor2Debug{
        java.srcDirs = ["${generatedJavaDirRoot}/flavor2/debug/"]
    }
    flavor2Release{
        java.srcDirs = ["${generatedJavaDirRoot}/flavor2/release/"]
    }
```